# How I can upload directly to S3 with Api Gateway?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-api-gateway

I want to upload directly to s3 with api gateway.

```
 file(png/jpeg)(upload)
```

user ----------------------> ApiGateway --------------------------------------> S3

user ----------------------> Custom Authorizer -------> api/upload -----> S3

is it possible?

Comment: API Gateway runs over your existing api or you can create a lambda function for it

Comment: @KushVyas How is it happening here?
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/api-gateway-content-encodings-examples-image-s3.html

Comment: You can take advantage of the binary support feature on API Gateway.

Answer (score 0):

Going through API Gateway is not scalable with size. There is a limitation of 10MB when you go through API.

We did it like this.

**For Authorization:**

CloudFront --> APIGateway --> Lambda ( returns SignedURL to Post to S3 )

**Image Upload:**

CloudFront --> S3 --> S3 EventTrigger --> Lambda (Post Image Processing)

Hope it helps.